# Wordpress - get meta data only from "published" articles

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, metadata

i have a dropdown with meta data from posts:

```
<form name="search" action="" method="get" class="form-dropdown">
        <select name="city">
        <option>Stadt wählen</option>
        <?php
            $metakey = 'city';
            $counties = $wpdb->query( 
                $wpdb->prepare( 
                    "
                    SELECT DISTINCT     meta_value
                    FROM                $wpdb->postmeta AS pm
                    JOIN                $wpdb->post AS p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
                    WHERE               meta_key = %s
                    AND                 post_status = 'published'
                    ORDER BY            meta_value ASC
                    ",
                    $metakey
                )
            );


            if ($counties) {
            foreach ($counties as $city) {
            echo "<option value=\"" . $city . "\">" . $city . "</option>";

            }
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Anzeigen" />
    </form>
```

but

```
AND post_status = published
```

seems to be wrong here. any idea how to show only the meta data from published posts? i get the posts per RSS feed with the plugin "FeedWordPress" and he puts the old posts to post status "retired" so they are shown. no i found no option in the plugin to put them to trash instead ...

Comment: post_status is not the field in postmeta table. You have to create join query with posts table

Comment: i think you are right, but i don't have any idea how to implement this. before?

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing single quotes in your query, as `published` is a string value and not another column. Ah, and as @Khushboo just mentioned, `post_status` is indeed a column of the posts table. So it have to look like this:

```
$wpdb->query( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
        SELECT DISTINCT     meta_value
        FROM                $wpdb->postmeta AS pm
        JOIN                $wpdb->post AS p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
        WHERE               meta_key = %s
        AND                 post_status = 'publish'
        ORDER BY            meta_value ASC
        ",
        $metakey
    )
);
```

But why don't you use other query functions like query_posts and the query params?

Comment: no that doesn't work i think Khushboo is right i have to get the tabeles from the post first and filter by "post status" before i get the metadata.

Comment: Right. Just saw that and was already updating my post. Now it should work.

Comment: updated my post with your code now i get no error but the pulldown is just empty ...

Comment: Actually the status is `publish`not `published` (see my changes).

Comment: Have you tried to run the query thourgh PhpMyAdmin or something similar? For me that worked. Are you sure, that your metakey is "city" and you have active rows for published posts?